# How to make ternary operation with server tag in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ternary-operator, server-tags

I have a Repeater who contain an html link balise. I want both the attribute name and the text to be "..." if Eval("Name")==null or Eval("Name") instead.
So I try to do this :

```
<a runat="server" class="a_equipement" onserverclick="displayEquipment" name='<%= Eval("Nom")%> == null ? "..." : <%# Eval("Nom")%>'> <%= Eval("Nom");%> == null ? "..." : <%# Eval("Nom");%> </a>
```

But it didn't work and I got a weird error : "DC6_Configuration_Equipement.aspx(42,214): error CS1026: ) expected"

Is it possible to do it like this or are there other possibilities ?

---

After some research I try this :

`name='<%# Eval("Nom") == null ? "..." : Eval("Nom")%>'`

But same probleme again... I work on IE8, could it be compability issues ?

Thank's again for all your answer :)

Comment: You shouldn't do this.  Use your code behind to manipulate the data into what you want to present.  Use the markup to just present the already computed value.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this. Then it will also work if `Nom` is `""`:

```
<a runat="server" name='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Nom").ToString()) ? "..." : Eval("Nom") %>'><%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Nom").ToString()) ? "..." : Eval("Nom") %></a>
```

The compatibility with IE 8 has nothing to do with the ternary operator itself.